# Index.php.Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Вот скрин:

[image]

Скажите, пожалуйста, что значит эта строка? Она одна в этом файле, а сайт работает, не могу понять, что это вообще такое? )

`devn::tmpl( basename(__FILE__, '.php') );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть класс devn, в нем есть метод tmpl в который в качестве параметра передается серверный путь к файлу из которого запущен скрипт с расширением php. И еще вверху написано "ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ ЭТОТ ФАЙЛ".

Comment:  а как узнать серверный путь?

Comment: echo(__FILE__);

Comment: basename возвращает последнюю часть пути, т.е. из /home/user123456/www/filename.php она вернет filename;  передавая еще один параметр php мы получаем filename.php